# sendfile() / TransmitFile() with encryption/decryption

Tags: linux, windows, networking, sendfile, transmitfile

How do I get the benefit of sendfile() (on Linux) and TransmitFile() (on Windows) if I also want to use encryption? Are there any Linux kernel modules or Windows drivers that provide this functionality? The only thing I've found this far is an implementation on FreeBSD by Netflix, but unfortunately that is not my two target platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Linux KTLS". It's pretty new/experimental though.